# Java refactoring code duplication

Tags: java, refactoring, code-duplication

I have code that repeats a lot, but I don't know how to refactor it properly.

I have a class `Foo`, it parses the network messages/data it receives from a socket and calls the corresponding `onEvent()` methods. `Foo` is purely a parser of network messages, it has no logic as to what action to take for the events it receives. Whoever wants to add such logic must subclass `Foo` and override the `onEvent()` methods.

```
abstract class Foo {
    void processNetwotkMessage(String message) {
        ...
        onEvent1(arg1, arg2, arg3)
        reutn;
        ...
        onEvent2(arg4);
        return;
        ...
        onEvent3()
        return;
        ...
        onEvent999(arg1337);
    }

    abstract protected void onEvent1(Arg1 arg1, Arg2 arg2, Arg3 arg3);
    abstract protected void onEvent2(Arg4 arg4);
    abstract protected void onEvent3();
    ...
    abstract protected void onEvent999(Arg1337 arg1337);
}
```

Now, my program is supposed to be modular, I have many separate module classes that want to receive those events and process them. The modules implement `Plugin` interface. The interface matches the `onEvent()` methods from `Foo`, but adds `PluginContext ctx` as the first argument.

```
interface Plugin {
    void onEvent1(PluginContext ctx, Arg1 arg1, Arg2 arg2, Arg3 arg3);
    void onEvent2(PluginContext ctx, Arg4 arg4);
    void onEvent3(PluginContext ctx);
    ...
    void onEvent999(PluginContext ctx, Arg1337 arg1337);
}
```

And now, to dispatch the events to the modules, I creating a module-aware subclass of `Foo` called `PluginSupporingFoo`.

```
class PluginSupporingFoo extends Foo implements PluginContext {
    List<Plugin> plugins;

    @Override
    protected void onEvent1(Arg1 arg1, Arg2 arg2, Arg3 arg3) {
        synchronized (plugins) {
            for (Plugin p : plugins) {
                p.onEvent1(this, arg1, arg2, arg3);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onEvent2(Arg4 arg4) {
        synchronized (plugins) {
            for (Plugin p : plugins) {
                if (PluginIsAllowedToBeAwareOfThisEvent(p, arg4)) {
                    p.onEvent2(this, arg4);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onEvent3() {
        synchronized (plugins) {
            for (Plugin p : plugins) {
                p.onEvent3(this);
            }
        }
    }

    ...

    @Override
    protected void onEvent999(Arg1337 arg1337) {
        synchronized (plugins) {
            for (Plugin p : plugins) {
                p.onEvent999(this, arg1337);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, whenever `Foo` calls one of `onEvent()` methods, the overrided method from `PluginSupporingFoo` gets called and then it dispatches this event to all of modules by calling the corresponding `onEvent()` method of `Plugin` interface, with one extra argument added -- `PluginContext ctx`. Sometimes there is also a condition whether to tell a module about an event or not, like you can see in `PluginSupporingFoo.onEvent2()`.

Now, there is a lot of code duplication going on that I would like to remove.

1. First off, `Plugin` interface and `Foo` class have almost identical methods. In fact, `Plugin` interface needs to have all `onEvent` methods `Foo` has but with `PluginContext ctx` as the an extra first argument.
2. Another code duplication is in `PluginSupporingFoo`. All `onEvent()` methods are pretty-much a copy of each other:

.

```
protected void on${EventName} ( ${ArgList} ) {
    synchronized (plugins) {
        for (Plugin p : plugins) {
            ${ OPTIONAL: if (filter(p, ${ArgList}.arg1)) { }
                p.on{EventName}(this, ${ArgList}.allArgs);
            ${ OPTIONAL: } }
        }
    }
}
```

And given that there are many many `onEvent` methods, it's frustrating to have so much copy-paste code and it would be hard to modify them all if needed.

Comment: Since Java 8 we have default methods, which means that you don't need both the interface as well as the abstract class. You can use the interface and provide default implementations to some of its methods. This will eliminate most of the code duplication. When you implement the interface you'll have to implement only the methods for which you didn't provide an implementation - unless there is an implementation that you'll want to override if course.

Comment: Please note that the methods in the interface and the abstract class have different number of arguments, and due to this your suggestion wouldn't work.

Comment: In that case, what's the point in having the interface? is the implementing class overriding both methods (with different signatures) ?

Comment: Please read my question, it explains what overrides what.

Comment: In that case, what is the use of abstract class Foo? it doesn't make sense to maintain both. Second, you're kinda implementing the observer pattern, so look into how it's supposed to be done: if certain plugins are supposed to "observe" only certain events - you should split your observer and observables to different types based on that. Doing this will not only refactor your code, but will also reduce it by removing lines like: `if (PluginIsAllowedToBeAwareOfThisEvent(p, arg4))`.

Comment: If you reached a point where you expect a plugin to listen to 1000 different types of events you definitely did something wrong along the way.

Comment: The abstract class `Foo` is there for the separation of concerns. It's just a parser that has no knowledge of the plugins and can be used without them. The plugin support is added in `PluginSupportingFoo`. Also, it doesn't matter if it's split in two classes like that or if you jumble it all in a single class, you will still have the same code with the very same problem of repetition, but now in a single class. It solves nothing.

Comment: Well, this *is* the observer pattern I'm using, I have read the chapter on observer pattern in Gamma, et al. Design Patterns book before posting this. Sadly, the example they provide is just with one event -- the clock tick. Also, it's not really 1000 events, it's less than so, around 30 for now and will expend, but it's still a lot of code duplication and I don't know how to get rid of it.

Comment: Different events shouldn't get treated the same, at least not by default. If there is duplicate code in the way the events are treated - then it would make sense to extract an abstract class.

Comment: What is your question Hot Coffee?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow... this is a poor design to have `eventXX( foo, bar, baz)` etc because each time you add a new event you must add a corresponding listener method.

Perhaps a better design would be to refactor this so that your `Foo` class only has a few or ideally one `onEvent()` method that takes a new `Event` interface

```
public class Foo{

  void onEvent(Event e){ ... }

} 

public interface Event{
     Object[] getArgs();

     //other Event specific methods
     ...
}
```

Then each of the `eventXX` methods would be a new implementation of the `Event` interface.

```
public class Event2 implements Event{

   public Object[] getArgs(){
       //Arg4 like in your code
       return new Object[]{ new Arg4() };
   }
}
```

the Plugin could could would also similarly only have 1 method

```
interface Plugin{

   onEvent(PluginContext ctx, Event e);

}
```

Now whenever you need to add a new Event it's just a new Event implementation and these interfaces don't need any extra methods.

Handlers can check the type of Event or you can make `EventType` or other kind of discriminator however you wish.

```
 class MyPlugin implements Plugin{
     public void onEvent(PluginContext ctx, Event e){
         //this is only useful if we only care about a few types
         if( e instanceOf Event2){
            //we know this is Arg4
            Arg4 arg4 = (Arg4) e.getArgs()[0];
            ...
         }

     }
 }
```

Now with Java Lambdas we we could even have a handler `Map<Class<? extends Event>, Function>` if you wanted to get fancy.

Comment: "because each time you add a new event you must add a corresponding listener method." Well, there is actually a class, let's call it `BasePlugin`, that implements Plugin interface, which has `{}` for all methods. That way modules can extend that class instead and override methods for whatever events they want to listen for. This means that modules don't have to implement a new event method if I add one to the Plugin interface, since I will add a `{}` implementation to the `BasePlugin`, which every module extends.

Comment: Your solution is nice in one way, but bad in another. It's nice because it allows to remove all the duplicate code I was complaining about, in essence this answers my original question, but you do this with the trade off that every module now must do this event dispatch `instanceOf` thing and cast the event's arguments into the correct types, which pushes the duplicate code on modules, since module1 and module2 would need to include the same code for this ritual, when I didn't have to cast the arguments or figure out what event it is with my original solution.

Comment: Actually, you don't really need to cast the arguments, just make `Event2` have `public Arg4 getArg4()`, so there is no code duplication between modules, besides the switch, which is perfectly fine. I like your solution.